# add Completion suggestion to index using java code for rest-high-level-client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My usecase is, I need have 4 fields in my index which are searchable through completion suggestion, but some of my fields can be empty or null while inserting, I tried using the following code while creating index, but this thrws an error as two of my fields are empty while inserting

```
    "CustomerName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "copy_to": [
                  "Suggestions.CustomerName"
                ]
              },
"FullAddress": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "copy_to": [
                  "Suggestions.FullAddress"
                ]
              },
"Contact": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "copy_to": [
                  "Suggestions.Contact"
                ]
              },
"CustomerId": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "copy_to": [
                  "Suggestions.CustomerId"
                ]
              }
```

How can I add *completion suggestion* in *elastic search* using java code? I'm using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You can start here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#_requesting_suggestions

Comment: so will it create a suggestion on the index?